# Applying two stylesheets for WordPress Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I would like to add two stylesheets to my WordPress theme. I would like to have one style sheet for my home page and another for my about page. The reason for this is I would like to apply different styles to my header and footer for these pages.

I tried the code below within function.php but of course it did not work.

```
wp_register_script ('add-about-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri('about'). '/about.css' );

wp_enqueue_script('add-about-css');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get_stylesheet_directory_uri does not accept any parameter.

Next

```
<?php if (is_page('$your_page_name/id/slug')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/about.css" type="text/css">
<?php }; ?>
```

Put this code in your header after linking to your default stylesheet. This will overwrite default styles with your new-style (for header, footer or whatever you defined). This is the case when you have same header with different style.

Alternately, if you are having two separate headers, then you can use

```
<?php get_header('custom') ?>
```

to load header-custom.php (if found else load default header.php) and custom styles for this can either be placed in style.css or can be included separately like

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_function');
function my_function(){
wp_enqueue_style('my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-custom-style.css');   
}
```

Comment: I have two headers 'header-about.php' and 'header.php'. Header.php is using the child theme css styles.css, but I do not want header-about.php to use styles.css but instead us about.css. Should I place the alternative code you have above in my custom about.php page or in function.php? If I place the script in function.php would the about.css styles take place in header.php as well as header-about.php?

Comment: Yes if you place in functions.php, it will overwrite styles for both headers, instead you need to place it in the template where you are loading your custom (about) header. There you don;t need to write it in a function or add action, you can directly enqueue your styles there using last line of above code.